# Jquery Script not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this script working fine in Chrome but in IE 8 or 9, this code is not working:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", '#CentroCusto_new option', function (event) {
    debugger;
    alert('oi');
    event.returnValue = false;
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

- In IE: F12 is open.
- Debugger and Alert is not called.
- jQuery v1.10.2
- No errors in console.
- I tried to change document to 'body', but not
  working too.
- When I remove option, function is called

How to solve this? I think IE is not accepting this selector, but why?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fp4WD/)

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Anything in your console?

Comment: i think **debugger;** is only accessible if the console is available/visible on IE.

Comment: There are many versions of IE; which one are you testing against/having issues with?

Comment: And why exactly are you using `debugger`, and why `returnValue` in jQuery, and why not `prop('selected')`. If you're using jQuery to get cross-browser code, why not use it?

Comment: OP says IE8 and 9 @TiesonT.

Comment: @putvande So it does. If it were a rattlesnake I'd been bit... thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using `e` to refer to your event variable. It shouldn't matter, but in old IE, `window.event` refers to the native event object. Also, I don't believe there is a `click` event on the `option` element in those versions of IE, only the `change` event on the parent `select`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, i need to 'prevent' options unselection. Because this option needs to be the selector. I used 'e' first. 'event' is my other attempt.

Comment: JSFiddle Created. http://jsfiddle.net/fp4WD/

Answer (score 1):

`debugger;` is pausing execution of your code - which is why `alert()` isn't firing

Comment: He says the `debugger` line isn't being called either.

Comment: IE version can matter and I think Adrian is right above - console should be open.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bwt76sk(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: He says `In IE: F12 is open.`

Comment: See comments and answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218212/how-to-launch-ie8-debugger-with-debugger-command